# Error: Cannot set UITableViewCell labels and images with custom cell class! Only able to load data with cell style: subtitle not custom

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have been working for the past 2 weeks to make my iphone app work with a custom UITableViewCell class and cannot set labels or images in the tableview cell with a custom class. I have been able to set a textLabel and detailTextLabel and an image to each cell with the standard cell type of subtitle.

When I try to create a custom cell in interface builder I go to the cells attributes select Custom as the cell style and give it an identifier of "cell". In the code I have created a class called `class DrinkListTableViewController: UITableViewController`. In the same file I have created a custom cell class called `class DrinkTableViewCell: UITableViewCell` as well as a struct for the data called `struct Drink`. I have verified that the data from my api call is good and loading as expected but I can only set the cells labels and image with `cell.imageView?.image =` `cell.textLabel?.text =` `cell.detailTextLabel?.text =` when really I want to use the custom cell class I created (Pls see code as reference).

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire

struct Drink {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let amount: Float
    let image: UIImage

    init(data: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = data["id"] as! String
        self.name = data["name"] as! String
        //self.amount = data["amount"] as! Float
        self.amount = ((data["amount"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue)!
        self.description = data["description"] as! String
        self.image = data["image"] as! UIImage
    }
}

class DrinkTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class DrinkListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var drinks: [Drink] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Drink Selection"
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        //tableView.register(DrinkTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        tableView.register(DrinkTableViewCell.self as AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        //tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DrinkTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        //tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 134
        //tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

        fetchInventory { drinks in
            guard drinks != nil else { return }
            self.drinks = drinks!
            //print("Data from API call: ", self.drinks)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
//            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
//                self?.tableView.reloadData()
//            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "pizzaSegue", sender: self.drinks[indexPath.row] as Drink)
        //trying another method below?
        //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UIViewController() as! PizzaViewController, animated: true)
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "pizzaSegue" {
            guard let vc = segue.destination as? PizzaViewController else { return }
            vc.pizza = sender as? Pizza
        }
    }

    private func fetchInventory(completion: @escaping ([Drink]?) -> Void) {
Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:4000/inventory", method: .get)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.isSuccess else { return completion(nil) }
            guard let rawInventory = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]?] else { return completion(nil) }
            let inventory = rawInventory.compactMap { pizzaDict -> Drink? in
                var data = pizzaDict!
                data["image"] = UIImage(named: pizzaDict!["image"] as! String)
                //print("Printing each item: ", Drink(data: data))
                //printing all inventory successful
                return Drink(data: data)
            }
            completion(inventory)
    }
}

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("ROWS: ", drinks.count)
        return drinks.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DrinkTableViewCell

        //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        let cell:DrinkTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DrinkTableViewCell

        cell.cellName?.text = drinks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.cellAmount?.text = String(drinks[indexPath.row].amount)
        cell.cellDescription?.text = drinks[indexPath.row].description
        cell.cellImage?.image = drinks[indexPath.row].image

//        cell.imageView?.image = drinks[indexPath.row].image
//        cell.textLabel?.text = drinks[indexPath.row].name
//        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = drinks[indexPath.row].description
//
        //print(cell.textLabel?.text)
        //print(cell.detailTextLabel?.text)

        print(cell.cellName?.text as Any)
        //print(cell.cellImage?.image)
        return cell
    }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 100.0
     }

}
```

The app does not crash when setting the cells labels and image with the custom class such like `cell.cellName?.text = drinks[indexPath.row].name` but the tableView just doesn't load anything, as in a blank tableView with number of section from drinks.count in the tableView override func numberOfRowsInSection. Please Help!

Comment: Why is `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DrinkTableViewCell` commented out? `let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")` won't work because it needs to be `as! DrinkTableViewCell` in your code you are just calling it as a normal cell with subtitle style

Comment: Yes you are correct but I have it as such just so something loads in the tableView cell. Using the ```let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DrinkTableViewCell``` and changing the way I set the cell text and image to the custom names I made, just loads a blank tableView

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you need to use:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DrinkTableViewCell
```

which in your code is commented out, rather than:

```
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

If that doesn't work try adding this into your custom cell class, it may be why you commented out it originally if it was not working:

```
 override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Edit:

Let's try without the storyboard.

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

//Declare items

let cellName = UILabel()
let cellAmount = UILabel()
let cellDescription = UILabel()
let cellImage = UIImageView()

//Setup the layouts of your items

func configureCustomCell() {

    contentView.backgroundColor = .clear

    contentView.addSubview(cellName)
    cellName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    cellName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    contentView.addSubview(cellAmount)
    cellAmount.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellAmount.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    cellAmount.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    contentView.addSubview(cellDescription)
    cellDescription.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellDescription.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    cellDescription.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    contentView.addSubview(cellImage)
    cellImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    cellImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    cellImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

}

 //Get ready for use

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Then just make sure you have in 'viewDidLoad':

```
tableView.register(DrinkTableViewCell.self as AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DTVCell")
```

Then in ' override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell' We should be able to do:

```
let cell:UserMessagesCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DTVCell") as! DrinkTableViewCell
```

and use like:

```
cell.cellName.text = "name"
```

Edit:

Sometimes the size of the cell row heights can effect custom cells. Try increasing the height of each row to make sure everything fits as sometimes you can get empty cells if the height is wrong.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Try using an if statement to avoid any issues with the API call.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.drinks.count == 0 {
        print("No Data Yet: ", drinks.count)
        return 0
    } else {
           print("ROWS: ", drinks.count)
           return self.drinks.count
    }
}
```

Comment: I have that first method ```let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DrinkTableViewCell``` commented out because it was not loading the tableView w/ any data but I have commented out the second method ```    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
``` and added those ```override init``` and ```required init``` and changed the way I am setting the labels and image to cell.cellName and cell.cellAmount and etc but this is proving not to work either :/

Comment: @AustinGriffith Did you set the Cell identifier in the storyboard? Another option, it's a bit more code but it is a bit more convenient when making a custom cell if you build the items in the class rather than using storyboard. I can update my answer with a full example that should work for you if you want.

Comment: I indeed have set the cell identifier in the storyboard I have double and triple checked the identifiers match in code and storyboard. I would love to see your example! I have gone through all the steps ppl have outlined on my other post but nothing is seeming to get me the result I need. It is very weird to me I can load data to the cell with the subtitle style but when trying to do it as custom it doesnt load anything.

Comment: @AustinGriffith did an edit, before you do that, switch out `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DrinkTableViewCell` with `let cell:UserMessagesCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserMessagesCell") as! UserMessagesCell`

Comment: Ok I tried to follow the edited answer you give above. I am still getting a blank tableView with empty blank cells. I have changed ```let cell =```  to ```let cell:DrinkTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DrinkTableViewCell```, I have added the ```func configureCustomCell()``` in the custom cell class: ```class DrinkTableViewCell: UITableViewCell``` but i do not see where this method is ever called. I have also changed in the viewDidLoad the line: ```tableView.register(DrinkTableViewCell.self as AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Comment: my mistake call `configureCustomCell()` right after `let cell:`

Comment: @AustinGriffith very weird unless your `tableView.reloadData()` is not being called properly it seems very strange so far.

Comment: @AustinGriffith just realised, did you set the tableView delegates? cannot see it in your question.

Comment: `tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I have indeed tried to call ```configureCustomCell()``` after the ```let cell:``` line but get this error: ```Use of unresolved identifier 'configureCustomCell'``` and the app will not build. I have set the delegate and the dataSource with those exact lines as you state above in the viewDidLoad() method^^^ already before you mention it and still no good :/

Comment: Did you do it as `cell.configureCustomCell()`?

Comment: I have set it with cell.configureCustomCell() and now getting an optional error:  ```Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value``` this is happening at the line ```contentView.addSubview(cellName)``` in the custom cell class. This is leading me back to the issue, when I try and print ```print(cell.cellName?.text as Any)``` it continue to print nil to the console. I believe there is something very funky going on above my understanding

Comment: Hmm everything i posted is from a working example so it should work. Can you update your question with the full code as it is now? It could be something obvious that we overlooked, but so far going through the checklist it is very strange why it wont work.

Comment: I just updated the code to what I currently have. I took out the method configureCustomCell because it was throwing the optional errors. One thing that I cannot explain is: I have a print statement in the ```    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("ROWS: ", drinks.count)
        return drinks.count
    }``` method. In the console when the app runs, it produces ```ROWS: 0``` twice and then finally ```ROWS: 4``` this might have something todo w/ values being nil upon being assigned to textLabel's in cell class.

Comment: @AustinGriffith I updated the answer if the data is working it may just be a problem with the layout and the height of the cell. That sounds like it is because when it first loads the data your API call is not done yet, I'll add a quick way to safely handle that in the answer and see if that helps.

Comment: I have gone ahead and added your suggested changes but this does not solve the issue. I added a little height to the row of each cell in the tableView heightForRowAt method and that is not the issue. I added the if/else condition in the  tableView numberOfRowsInSection method and the output to the console is still the same as the way I had it. The output looks like such: ```No Data Yet:  0
No Data Yet:  0
ROWS:  4``` I do indeed think this has something to do with the problem because the tableView is loading as blank.

Comment: @AustinGriffith That seems to be correct that it would do that, when it says `ROWS: 4` That is when you are called `tableView.reloadData()` after the call so that seems correct, before that there would be nothing. Is the entire tableView empty, or is it 4 empty rows?

Comment: I  have just gone and double checked this but it is indeed just the 4 blank cells not an entire empty tableView

Comment: @AustinGriffith Okay sounds like everything is fine in relation to the tableview and the data. On interface builder did you set the Custom Class to your cell class?

Comment: @AustinGriffith and are all the constraints set on the items in the contentView of the cell? also remove the `override init` and `required inits`  from the class as they are only needed if we dont use storyboard, and remove the `tableView.register(DrinkTableViewCell.self as AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")` from viewdidload as tthe storyboard handles that aswell.